Power BI / DAX: Force a null value to be like previous one
As visual, I have the following table:



Client
year 1
year 2
year 3
year 4
year 5




AAA
10€






BBB



20€




Values in this table represent yearly potential of our clients and are related only to year of signing contract.
I would like to get those values in each year after signing contract year, like this:



Client
year 1
year 2
year 3
year 4
year 5




AAA
10€
10€
10€
10€
10€


BBB



20€
20€



Is there a way to get this result?
